# Derivative of a delta function when using Jefimenko's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I was using Jefimenko's equations to solve a problem our Electrodynamics teacher sent us involving a infinite wire with current $$I(t) = q_0 \delta(t).$$ So we have to obtain electric, $\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t),$ and magnetic, $\vec{B}(\vec{r}, t),$ fields produced by that current. That make me find a situation with which I have never coped before and that is integrating the derivative of the delta function.

If we check Jefimenko's equations and put our current in the $z$ axis, we see that $$\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t) = - \frac{\hat{z}}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 c^2} \int_{z'_{-}}^{z'_{+}} \frac{\dot{I}(\vec{r}, t_r)}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z'^2}} \mathrm{d}z', $$ being $t_r = t - \sqrt{\rho^2+z'^2}/c$ the retarded time and $z'_{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{c^2t^2-\rho^2}$ the limits of integration as the further points don't contribute to the field in the instant $t$. As it can clearly be seen, I find myself in front of a derivative of a delta function inside my integral, but without the company of any function depending on $t$. I say this because I have seen proofs of $f(x)\delta'(x) = -f'(x)\delta(x)$, but that doesn't seem to be the situation here.

I'm not looking for you to tell me how to solve the problem, just how to manage this tricky derivative of the delta function.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can express $\dot{I}$ in terms of $\frac{d I}{dz'}$.

Comment: Be warned! If you apply "what everybody knows" about derivations and use it on the delta "function" you can end up proving 0=1.

Comment: @secavara $I = q_0 \delta(t) \neq I(z')$!

Comment: @GyroGearloose I know, that's why I'm asking how to approach that question xD

Comment: Patrick, on some items, which prove out to be very fundamental, Maths and Physics are "divided by common language", using same names and symbols for completely different things.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I don't know how that relates to my question. I don't think I understand

Comment: @Patrick it doesn't. It is just a general hint to not literally trust anything from "the other side". Prime example are Physics *metrics*, like Minkovsky metric, which isn't a metric in Maths talk at all.

Comment: Could you expand your expression for $\vec E(\vec r,t)$ so that the Dirac delta was explicitly visible there? This might give you a clearer view of the problem, and help others concentrate on its core.

Comment: @Patrick that's not what I meant. What I am saying is that $\dot{I}(\vec{r},t_r)$ can be expressed in terms of derivatives with respect to $z'$, which is the integration variable here. You can do this because you know exactly the dependence of $t_r$ on $t$ and $z'$: $\frac{d}{d z'} \delta(t_r) = \frac{d t_r}{d z'} \frac{d}{d t_r} \delta(t_r) = \frac{d t_r}{d z'} \frac{d}{d t} \delta(t_r)$.